# How to Update oracle table using Python passing arguments

Tags: python-3.x

I need to pass 2 arguments to my update statement.

I first get the distinct ID's from TBL1 into a List as below. This works fine

```
 unit_no=[]
 sql = """SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM TBL1"""
 tmp_cursor=self.DB_conn.cursor()
 for rec in tmp_cursor.execute(self.orcl_query1)
        unit_no.append(rec)
```

Then, I get a values from another table using the above result. This also is working fine.

```
while i < len(unit_no):
    sql = 'SELECT COL1 FROM TBL2 WHERE ID = :1)
    tmp_cursor1=self.DB_conn.cursor()
    tmp_cursor1.execute(sql,unit_no[i])
    for result in tmp_cursor1
        input1=result
        sql = """update tbl1 set col1 = :1 where id = :2"""
        tmp_cursor2=self.DB_conn.cursor() 
        tmp_cursor2.execute(sQL,col1, unit_no[i])
```

I am getting error - function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given), for the above line.

How do I pass 2 values as input to the update statement